# Group by based on user_id but without using join and sub query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How to group by this scenario based on user_id without using join and sub query, result I need the latest date.

```
user_id    name            date
1          mike           14-12-2015
2          bob            14-12-2015
1          Thomas         15-12-2015
2          john           15-12-2015
```

The output should be latest data stored in db.

Comment: And the output should be?

Comment: output should be latest data stored in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query :-

```
select *
from table t1 
where date=(SELECT MAX(t2.date)
              FROM table t2
              WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id)
```

Comment: this sub query already working but without sub query is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, max(date)
from your_table
group by user_id
```

Comment: select `user_id` max(date)
from `test`
group by `user_id`  is not working

Comment: @FakkirmohamedSait, maybe because you did not enter the comma before `max(date)`